# Android - Eclipse ignoring Java code, only runs from XML file

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to Android development in Eclipse, and for some reason, when trying to run my Java code, Eclipse ignores it and only runs the XML code.

Here is my Java code so far:

```
package com.example.boat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ScrollView mainView = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout results = new LinearLayout(this);

    mainView.addView(mainLayout);
    mainLayout.addView(results);
    results.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    TextView mhs = new TextView(this);
    mhs.setText("Maximum hull speed:");
    mainLayout.addView(mhs);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.boat"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ser421assignment4.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?  I prefer to use Java, not XML.

Comment: those are two absolutely unrelated code.

Comment: What do u mean ignores it ?

Comment: I mean that when I build and run my project, I don't see my TextView that I have in my Java code.

Comment: I have noticed if you have the XML page showing in the Eclipse editor when you try to run the application, it tries to run the xml page instead of the application.  Make sure the java code is showing in the window.

Comment: Tow things to understand.  XML is not code, it's just data and you cannot "run" XML, just like I can't run a PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think isn't running but the only thing that will happen here is that your `activity_main.xml` will be inflated because of this line

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

All of the Java code before this is just creating `View`s but not being added to the inflated `View` with `setContentView()`. Once you call `setContentView()` that is what will be displayed. If you want to set those `View`s on this `layout` then you need to do it after your call to `setContentView()` and you have to add them to that `layout`...not just on each other.

However, in this situation, I see no need to create those dynamically. Just add them to your `activity_main.xml` and take those out of `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I simply replaced this line with `setContentView(mainView)`